# JAWS is not announcing Button state collapsed /expanded for a menu button when aria-haspopup="menu"

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a menu button like this

```
 <app-my-buton [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Open Content"></app-my-buton>
```

but JAWS is not announcing the button state collapsed/expanded for a menu button when aria-haspopup="menu"

What can I do to make Jaws announce the button state?

Comment: You might need to add `aria-expanded="true"` or `"false"` to signal to the screen reader that the control is expanded or collapsed. It should cause that state to be announced by the screen reader

Comment: @RedMercury Mercury Yes. already added aria-expanded, but JAWS is not announcing an expanded/collapsed state. but it works with other screen readers like NVDA, chromeVox